# Executing an xmgrace batch with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, popen, batch-processing

I have to make graphs from several files with data. I already found a way to run a simple command

```
xmgrace -batch batch.bfile -nosafe -hardcopy
```

in which batch.bfile is a text file with grace commands to print the graph I want. I already tried it manually and it works perfectly. To do this with several files I just have to edit one parameter inside batch.bfile and run the same command every time I make a change.

I have already written a python code which edits batch.bfile and goes through all the data files with a for cycle. In each cycle step I want to run the mentioned command directly in the command line.

After searching a bit I found two solutions, one with os.system() and another with subprocess.Popen() and I could only make subprocess.Popen() work without giving any errors by writing:

```
subprocess.Popen("xmgrace -batch batch.bfile -nosafe -hardcopy", shell=True)
```

Problem is, this doesn't do anything in practice, i.e., it just isn't the same as running the command directly in the command line. I already tried writing the full directory for the batch.bfile but nothing changed.

I am using Python 2.7 and Mac OS 10.7

Comment: Nothing is changed as in nothign returned or printed?

Comment: No files were generated by grace, I mean. If I ran the command directly in the command line, the graph would be generated normally and without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked running xmgrace from the command line using sh?  (i.e. invoke /bin/sh, then run xmgrace... which should be the same shell that Popen is using when you set shell=true).

Another solution would be to create a shell script (create a file like myscript.sh, and run chmod +x from the terminal).  In the script call xmgrace:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmgrace -batch batch.bfile -nosafe -hardcopy
```

You could then test that myscript.sh works, which ought to pick up any environment variables that might be in your profile that might differ from python.  If this works, you could call the script from python's subprocess.Popen('myscript.sh').  You can check what the environment variables are set in python for subprocess by running:

```
import os
os.environ
```

Comment: I didn't quite get what you meant by the environment variables as I don't quite understand their function in all this. Nevertheless, I creater a file named batch.sh, ran it on the directory I wanted by typing "./batch.sh" (after chmod -x'ing) and it ran perfectly. In python I tried subprocess.Popen("./batch.sh") but nothing happened :\ I also tried with the full directory and nothing :\

Comment: And yes, I invoked /bin/sh, ran the same command and everything worked fine :\

Comment: You were right, I finally understood what you meant by the PATH stuff and yes, xmgrace was not on python's PATH. By writing the full path of xmgrace in the script I could make everything work correctly. Thank you so much and excuse my ignorance about the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/graceplot/

Comment: Does this process the data as fast as grace normally would? I ask this because previously I used python with matplotlib to do my plots and I stopped because for large amounts of data (100k+ elements) python was just struggling with it :\ I don't know if it was the fault of python or matplotlib.

Comment: It might give some over head but should be as fast as grace, you could try it out to see if it is, I couldn't find anything about speed.

Answer (score 0):

When use use Popen, you can capture the application's output to stdout to stderr and print it within your application - this way you can see what is happening:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
ps = Popen(reportParameters,bufsize=512, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
if ps:
   while 1:
      stdout = ps.stdout.readline()
      stderr = ps.stderr.readline()
      exitcode = ps.poll()
      if (not stdout and not stderr) and (exitcode is not None):
         break
      if stdout:
         stdout = stdout[:-1]
         print stdout
      if stderr:
         stderr = stderr[:-1]
         print stderr
```

Comment: Problem is this command doesn't produce any output. It only generates a graph in the folder indicated inside batch.bfile :\

Comment: Did you write the full path for both xmgrace and and the batch.bfile?  Sometimes the working directory of python is in an unexpected place - could be the output is landing there.  Try in your code import os, and print os.path.realpath('.')

Comment: I put this piece of code you suggested me in python and the output was this: ./batch.sh: line 2: xmgrace: command not found. Does this have to do with the environment stuff you talked about?

Comment: You can try running xmgrace with the full path (eg. /usr/local/bin/xmgrace) - if you're not sure of the full path, you can type "which xmgrace" at the terminal (not python).  The environment contains the PATH, which is a list of the directories to search for applications.  When you run from the terminal, xmgrace is on the path, but it looks like when you run from python that it is not.

Comment: Actually, subprocess.Popen() would give you an error if it couldn't find xmgrace.  So xmgrace is running, but not working properly.  It looks like xmgrace uses other environment variables, such as "GRACE_HOME".  On my machine (osx / snow leopard), typing "env" at the terminal provides the same environment variables as typing "import os; os.environ" in python.

Comment: My xmgrace is in /opt/local/bin/xmgrace. I already corrected this in the sh script :)